# Using Option Button to set a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with three sheets.

The first sheet contains two option buttons and a button. When the user clicks the button I want to copy the appropriate sheet (sheet 2 for option button 1, sheets 3 for option button 2), to a new workbook and prompt the user to save the new workbook.

```
Dim SheetName As String
Dim OptionButton1, OptionButton2 As OptionButton

If OptionButton1 = True Then Set SheetName = Sheet2Name
If OptionButton2 = True Then Set SheetName = Sheet3Name

Sheets(SheetName).Copy
If MsgBox("Would you like to save the new workbook?", vbYesNo _
    + vbQuestion, "") = vbYes Then
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).show
End If
```

I receive the run-time error

> object variable not set

on this line:

```
If OptionButton2 = True Then Set SheetName = Sheet3Name
```

When I hover over the line, it says `OptionButton2`is `Nothing`, but `Optionbutton1` is `Empty`. I tried changing the variable declaration to:

```
Dim OptionButton1 As OptionButton
Dim OptionButton2 As OptionButton
```

but then both `OptionButton`s are `Nothing`.

Comment: You are not assigning the actual option buttons to your variables. Are you using Form controls or ActiveX controls?

Comment: I am using form controls

Comment: `OptionButton1` si DIM-ed as Variant in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it like that:

```
Dim OptionButton1 As OptionButton
Set OptionButton1 = Sheet2.Shapes("Option Button 1").DrawingObject
```

Comment: Do you mind if I edit my answer into yours for a complete answer?

Answer (score 0):

You only use set for objects, not primitive types like strings and numbers.

```
If OptionButton1.Value = xlOn Then 
    SheetName = "Sheet2Name"
ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = xlOn Then 
    SheetName = "Sheet3Name"
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: I believe the Value property of a Forms type option button is either xlOn or xlOff, not True or False.

Comment: Good call @ExcelDevelopers. I should have checked before posting.